# Unable to access amazon RDS mysql instance from lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail, aws-vpc

I am new to AWS and not a network admin, mere a developer, and need your help.

I am unable to connect to my aws RDS (mysql) from my lightsail ubuntu instance. when trying to connect, it just wait for a minute and then fails.
I am unable to ping my RDS either.

here is the setup
the lightsail instance has vpc peering enabled in lon-zone-A
I have created a mysql RDS instance in aws and used default vpc peering. mysql is restricted to VPC and using default security group which has a rule for inbound - All traffic for default security group source

the default VPC have 2 subnets in CIDR `172.31.16.0/20` and `172.31.0.0/16` for two availability zone A and B.
In route table of the subnet, i have
`172.26.0.0/16` as destination and target to vpc peering which further has

Requester VPC CIDRs `172.26.0.0/16`
Accepter VPC CIDRs `172.31.0.0/16`

My lightsail instance has private IP `172.26.15.xxx` and in lon-Zone-A
When i ping my mysql intance, i get ip `172.31.10.9`

command using to connect `mysql -h xxxxxx.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u db_master_username -p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve. it. 
I had to add my lightsail instance IP CIDR in the RDS inbound rule as mysql/aurora TCP allowed traffic.
:-)

Comment: You will now also note that you still can't ping RDS.  That is normal/expected behavior.  RDS doesn't respond to pings.

Comment: Would Aurora also work?
I am attempting to use Aurora as the database, have added the inbound rule to the security group already, however I still cannot access the database.

Answer (score 15):

To enable access from AWS Lightsail to AWS RDS you can accomplish in two separate ways:

**Method 1.**

1. Make RDS publicly accessible.

   In RDS pick you instance and click 'Modify'. In section 'Network & Security' choose 'Publicly accessible' to Yes. Apply settings and wait until they are effective. Your RDS has public IP now.
2. Add your Lightsail **public IP** to the RDS security group inbound traffic.

   Use CIDR: x.x.x.x/32 where x.x.x.x is your Lightsail instance public IP.

**Method 2. (better, RDS with no public IP)**

1. Make sure you Lightsail instance is in the same Availability Zone as RDS.
2. Set up [VPC peering](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/lightsail-how-to-set-up-vpc-peering-with-aws-resources) beetween Lightsail VPC and Amazon VPC.
3. Add your Lightsail **local IP** to the RDS security group inbound traffic.

Comment: Would peering work when the Lightsail VPC and Amazon VPC are in different AZ but same region? The reason stems from multi-AZ failover and scalability.

Comment: No they both have to be in the same region.